# Windows.old not created by new install - is uninstall an option?

Tags: windows-7

I bought Windows 7 Home 32bit, then upgraded to Windows 7 Pro 32 bit.
I have the disc for Home but no disc for Pro since the upgrade.
Recently hal.dll corrupted.
I thought the OS had been making restore points but I found no way to restore the system to a previous state.

I created a boot disc with X15-65804.iso from Digital River.
I couldn't fix the .dll with the boot disc and was running out of time so I tried a Custom install.
That created a Windows.old folder but there's nothing in it.  I'm afraid all my files are lost.

I'm hoping they're recoverable.
Is there a way to 'uninstall'/restore the system back to where I just had the hal.dll problem?
Or have the old system's files been put somewhere else?
Maybe I need to Activate the new OS before the contents of Windows.old are accessible...?

Thanks

Comment: Your files were overwritten when you reinstalled your operating system.  The Windows.old is likely from a previous upgrade or failed attempt to do something since its empty

Answer (score 1):

Boot from [Windows 7 DVD, go to the repair options, select the command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-7)

[image]

and run this command:

```
sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=c:\ /OFFWINDIR=c:\windows
```

(Replace C with the drive letter where you Windows is).

this scans for corrupted files and tries to repair them. Is it able to fix the corrupted HAL.dll?

Comment: I didn't know about that command line script in time.  I did a Custom install which apparently erased everything without making a backup of the original OS.  That's why I was hoping there was a way to 'uninstall' back to the original state.  I didn't imagine that a corrupted hal.dll would mean that all my files would be wiped-out in the process of fixing it.